# How do you implement a javascript in rails views using bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

Without bootstrap it is fine, i can define in a particular rails view with a

```
<script>
 $function(){

 });
</script>
```

But how do i define it in rails view with bootstrap? I've done the same without and it doesn't show the output - but in the source i saw the script lines above.

The script uses jQuery-UI with booklet jQuery.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need a rails generator for view? Or you mean css framework bootstrap?

Comment: It is for twitter bootstrap. I used without twitter bootstrap and the javascript loads. With it, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the javascript functions in your javascript assets folder and then call the function in your view or create an helper for it. take a look at this example for adding more fields to a nested attribute:

View:

```
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Contact</legend>
      <%= f.input :name, :autofocus => true %>
      <%= f.input :email %>
      <%= f.input :vat_number %>
      <%= f.input :gender, :collection => [:male, :female] %>
      <%= f.input :birth_date,  :as => :date, :start_year => Date.today.year - 90,
        :end_year => Date.today.year - 12%>
    </fieldset>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :addresses do |a| %>
      <%= render "address_fields", :f => a %>
    <% end%>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "last_id" %>
    <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Address", f, :addresses %> </p>
  </div>
```

Helper:

```
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
    end
    link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
  end
```

and in your helper.js (in javascript assets)

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
    var new_id = new Date().getTime();
    var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");
    $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
    $(link).parent().append('<input type="hidden" name="click" value="true" />');
    $("#last_id").val(new_id);
}
```

Comment: I think my javascript implementation isn't as complex. https://gist.github.com/muhammadn/8f8f57443e0f48e7a6e1

I'm still learning helpers but i'm unsure how it would help me in this case.

Comment: I have implemented the javascript code in books.js.erb in app/assets/javascripts/books.js.erb

It's a simpler implementation but @Paulo Fidalgo - Thanks, i'll look it up as well since i need to learn about it and use it later on. :)

Comment: Reference website for my above solution:

http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html