# Rails form duplication with jQuery & CSRF token

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a working form in my file. I want to duplicate this form so that it can add multiple programs. If I press "Add Program" it should append an extra form as same as the first one, to that form, without losing the CSRF. How can I do that?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just cloned the form using:

```
var clonedElement = $(this).parent().clone();
```

And appended to where ever I need using:

```
$(this).parent().parent().children().append(clonedElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you trying to create nested forms?
Remember that cloning will persist the input ID's, make sure you want that.

Check this answer for an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/16729580/1006863